# iOS Storing and Cacheing on Storage limit

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am storing and caching images on the TMP Directory.

Last time I checked the usage it was 50MB. Is there any limitations on the usage of the storage?

Would Apple reject the App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation about the amount of information that you store in this directory, but you have to take into account that the App Store Guidelines say that the information stored in the `/tmp` directory has to be removed when the application exits. Breaking this requirement could make that Apple reject your application.

Comment: If I store on the Document Directory instead of the /tmp will it affect the Acceptance of the App?

Comment: no, but probably they will request you mark the information that you store to not get included in the backup, you can see how to do it [in here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html). Another option is to put it in the Cache directory, the information in Cache is not included in the backup but if the system get out off space it will remove the content this directory automatically